# Retrieve row value and column name using Parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse within a Swift App.

How do get the `SlotName` and appropriate day field(s) on records where `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday` and/or `Friday` equals `"username"`.

[image: Database]

Comment: So you want to get all the rows where username is equal to the current user?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Ran. I want to get Weekday name and Slotname. For Instance if username is exist in Tuesday column and SlotName 10.00 - 11.00, then I want to get Slotname = 10.00 - 11.00  and Weekday = Tuesday for the currentuser. This is appointment booking database. So now I hope you have a idea of the database scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this in three steps:

1. Retrieve all records where:

   - `Monday` = Username
   - `Tuesday` = Username
   - etc.
2. Then check to see what the `SlotName` is for the given record.
3. Then for the returned record, iterate through to see if:

   - `Monday` = Username
   - `Tuesday` = Username
   - etc.

Where a record's value for a given week day is `True` (for example: `Monday = Username`), then put this into an array. This would give you a list of appointments and the times of the said appointments for a given username.